# Can you cut cucumbers when you make them in brine?

Tags: brining, pickling, cucumbers, pickles

I'm trying to make Polish style cucumbers in brine (ogórki kiszone) but my jars are too small to fit cucumbers I can get in the supermarket. Can I just cut them or the lack of skin will change the fermentation process significantly?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how it would change the process. Besides, I've seen the same pickled fermented cucumbers cut, although lengthwise. However you cut them, it will be fine.

Comment: There's one change -- it works faster.  As the flesh is exposed, it processes quicker than it would if it has to go through the skin, and it doesn't have to go as deeply to affect all of the vegetable being brined.  Where this is really noticeable is when they're been left to sit for extended periods (eg, canned and left for a couple of years).  The cut ones can end up being almost mush and really unpleasant to eat.